# QComboBox with single value: Select this value

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a QComboBox which changes its selection possibilities depending on certain conditions. 
Because of special combinations, it might have only one selection left over, which has to be "confirmed" by the user, preferably by looking at all possible selections, seeing that there is only one, and then selecting this.

My problem: If a user selects the only option there is, the value is never set, i.e. no signal is sent.
Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SIGNAL(highlighted(...)) instead of SIGNAL(activated(...)). Or do a setCurrentIndex(-1) before, this should work with activated().

Comment: doh... high praise to my blindness. Thanks